# Ext JS 4 checkboxfield not displayed

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

has anyone else ran into a problem with ext js checkboxes not showing up?  We have tried everything, even download the architect software and it still won't display...  Any ideas?

I have a feeling it's like a css/include file we're missing, but I've looked all over the Internet and I still can't find a solution.

```
 {
            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
            anchor: '100%',
            fieldLabel: 'Label2',
            boxLabel: 'Box Label2'
        }
```

Here's the panel:

```
 var manForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                width: 800,
                style: 'position: relative; left: 20px;',
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                id: 'man_form',
                title: 'Mobile Information',
                waitMsgTarget: true,
                fieldDefaults: {
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    labelWidth: 85,
                    msgTarget: 'side'
                },
                items: [
                        {                       
                            xtype: 'container',
                           padding: '10px',
                         defaults: { height: 28 },
                            items: [{
                                          xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                                           name: 'id',
                                             id: 'id',
                                    },
                                    {
                                           xtype:'hiddenfield',
                                            name: 'item_id',
                                              id: 'item_id'
                                    },  
                                    {    xtype: 'container', 
                                        layout: 'hbox',  
                                      defaults: { height: 28 },
                                        margin: ' 0 10 0 0',
                                         items: [{
                                                       xtype:'textfield',
                                                  fieldLabel: 'Number',
                                                        name: 'ItemNumber',
                                                          id: 'ItemNumber',
                                                  labelWidth: 45,
                                                       width: 345, 
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                       xtype:'textfield',
                                                  fieldLabel: 'Name',
                                                        name: 'ItemName',
                                                          id: 'ItemName',
                                                  labelWidth: 70,
                                                       width: 425,                                                  
                                               }] 
                                    },
                                    {
                                           xtype: 'textfield',
                                      fieldLabel: 'Category List',
                                      labelWidth: 140,
                                           width: 700,
                                            name: 'CategoryList',
                                              id: 'CategoryList'
                                    },
                                    {
                                           xtype: 'textfield',
                                      fieldLabel: 'Short Desc For Cat List',
                                            name: 'ShortDescriptionForCategoryList',
                                              id: 'ShortDescriptionForCategoryList',
                                      labelWidth: 140,
                                           width: 600
                                    },
                                    {  xtype: 'container', 
                                      layout: 'hbox',  
                                      margin: ' 0 10 0 0',
                                       items: [{
                                                       xtype: 'textfield',                                        
                                                        name: 'BasePrice',
                                                  fieldLabel: 'Base Price',
                                                          id: 'BasePrice',
                                                  labelWidth: 140,
                                                       width: 270,
                                                       height: 28
                                                },
                                                {
                                                       xtype: 'textfield',                                        
                                                        name: 'RetailPrice',
                                                  fieldLabel: 'Retail Price',
                                                          id: 'RetailPrice',
                                                  labelWidth: 140,
                                                       width: 270,
                                                      height: 28
                                              },{
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                anchor: '100%',
                fieldLabel: 'Label2',
                boxLabel: 'Box Label2'
            }


                                              ] 
                                    },
                                    {
                                           xtype: 'textfield',                                        
                                            name: 'ItemImages',
                                      fieldLabel: 'Item Images',
                                              id: 'ItemImages',
                                      labelWidth: 140,
                                           width: 700                                                  
                                    },
                                    {
                                           xtype: 'textfield',                                        
                                            name: 'ItemPrimaryImageUrl',
                                      fieldLabel: 'Primary Image URL',
                                              id: 'ItemPrimaryImageUrl',
                                      labelWidth: 140,
                                           width: 700                                                   
                                    },                                     
                                    {
                                           xtype: 'textfield',                                        
                                            name: 'ItemPrimaryImageAltText',
                                      fieldLabel: 'Primary Image Alt Text',
                                              id: 'ItemPrimaryImageAltText',
                                      labelWidth: 140,
                                           width: 700                                                   
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                           xtype: 'textfield',                                        
                                            name: 'ItemThumbnailUrl',
                                      fieldLabel: 'Thumbnail URL',
                                              id: 'ItemThumbnailUrl',
                                      labelWidth: 140,
                                           width: 700                                                   
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                           xtype: 'textfield',                                        
                                            name: 'ItemThumbnailAltText',
                                      fieldLabel: 'Thumbnail Alt Text',
                                              id: 'ItemThumbnailAltText',
                                      labelWidth: 140,
                                           width: 700                                                   
                                    },                                         
                                    {
                                           xtype: 'button',
                                            text: 'Update',
                                            name: 'new_button',
                                              id: 'new_button',
                                           style: 'margin-left:720px; margin-bottom:5px',
                                         handler: function(event, toolEl, panel){

                                              Ext.Msg.show({
                                                   title:'Update Data',
                                                   msg: 'Are you sure you want to update these settings?',
                                                   buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                                                   icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
                                                   fn: function(btn){
                                                     if (btn === 'yes'){

                                                       var obj = manForm.getForm().getValues();
                                                       for (var prop in obj) {
                                                         store.getAt(0).set(prop,obj[prop]);                
                                                        //alert(prop + " : " + obj[prop]);
                                                       }

                                                       store.update();
                                                       store.load();
                                                     }
                                                   }
                                              });
                                         }
                                  },
                         ]

                    }],
        });
```

Comment: I plugged your code right in and was able to see the checkbox just fine.  It probably is some custom CSS getting in the way.  Have you inspected the `hbox` containing the checkbox to see what the calculated CSS looks like?

Comment: Hi kev, thank you for your help.  I commented the hbox layout ref out and it's still not showing up...  Any other ideas?

Comment: kevhender, that was it...  I commented out on of the css files and the checkbox showed up.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I didnt really test your code like kevhender did. But the fact that it works for him but not you, makes me think that you dont have the image file that extjs uses for a checkbox. Usually it is placed in images/form/checkbox.gif. 
please check your images folder once. Also dev tools (either Firebug or chrome dev tools) console should throw an error if thats the case - saying "file could not be found at path blahblah" or something.

Comment: Interesting.  I will check the image file and css...  I've never used the hbox before, so I may have a question about that.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I checked for the checkbox.gif and it's there...  No error in Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools